# catch IndexOutOfBoundsException in get() method in java

Tags: java, arraylist, try-catch, indexoutofboundsexception, getter

I would truly appreciate if someone could help me to understand why my code won't work the way it should:

I'd like to catch the exception when the index being tested (in the main class) is out of bound from my ArrayList in the getter method.

It should behave like: if the index (testing using 8) is out of bound from the ArrayList (length of 5), then the program will not get any value and print out statement saying Will Skip, and keep moving to the next line. If the index is not out of bound, return the value from the ArrayList.

What I have below works only when there is a "return" value in the Catch(). I know it is because the getter is asking to return a double. But I don't know how to fix this to behave the way stated above. Thank you so much!

**Main Driver class for testing:**

```
TestValue object = new TestValue();

System.out.println("The value is " + object.getListValue(8));

...other methods like print values, set new values etc.
```

**TestValue class:**

```
public double getListValue(int index) { 

     try {  
        listValue.get(index);
        while (index <0 || index >= listValue.size()) { 
        }
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Can't get value. Will skip this request. ");
        return listValue.get(0); // I don't want to return any values
    }
    return listValue.get(index);
}
```

Comment: This is it, you either return something or throw an exception, there are no other choices

Comment: If you want to catch and skip, you need to do that *outside* of `getListValue`, in your driver code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the definition of your method was `public double`,
you have to return a `double` unless you throw an exception.
If you really don't want to return a value, you can return `0.0`.

Comment: How would I return a null? I did try "return null;" in catch(). It gave me an typemismatch error. Thanks!

Comment: you just need to change the "double" to "Double".then you can return null